# Checkbox with font awesome for ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

```css
.fancy-checkbox input[type="checkbox"],
.fancy-checkbox .checked {
    display: none;
}
 
.fancy-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .checked
{
    display: inline-block;
}
 
.fancy-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .unchecked
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="fancy-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-microphone unchecked"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-microphone-slash checked"></i>
  Mute
</label>
```

Hello. I've been tested countless examples for checkbox with font awesome but all off them use :checked which make them not usable in ie8. The problem is that my whole website is ie8 compatible (i've worked hard to keep it that way) so, does anyone has a solution that is ie8 compatible?

Any jquery solution is welcomed, as long is a few lines of code.
I have added a example (which i liked). Thanks

THIS IS AN UPDATE

I have managed to find a small plugin that works in ie8 but it has one issue. It works with images instead of font awesome. I tried to replace the first checkbox image with a font awesome and that is not showing. I do not know why, because in other areas i have added font awesome directly in style via font-family: FontAwesome; content: '\f107';

So, what do i miss?
And here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/yt12mzeh/
First area (checkbox) should show the font awesome and it doesn't.

Fix

Turns out i forgot to add :before to the class where i wanted to show font awesome.

Comment: Duplicate the style and add JavaScript to add a checked class.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfidlle? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use event bubbling to catch all the relevant events.

```
$(document.body).on("change","input[type=checkbox]",function() {
    // jQuery used for convenience with IE8 compatibility ;)
    var t = $(this);
    if( t.prop("checked")) t.addClass("checked");
    else t.removeClass("checked");
});
```

Now use `.checked` instead of `:checked` :)

Comment: I tried like this http://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/uecn4ocw/ but is not working in ie8. Or i didn't made the adjustments as you mentioned?